# Hours needed to go from Private Pilot AMEL to ASEL

Tags: faa-regulations, cfi

I was wondering about the minimum hours required to go from Private Multi-Engine Land to Private Single engine land.

Comment: Welcome to Aviation.SE! Since this might differ between jurisdictions, please add a corresponding tag (e.g. [easa-regulations] or [faa-regulations]).

Comment: What country are you asking about?

Answer (score 2):

For an FAA applicant.

- 3 hours of cross-country flight training in a single-engine airplane.
- 3 hours of night flight training in a single-engine airplane
- 3 hours of flight training in a single-engine airplane by reference to instruments
- 3 hours of flight training in a single-engine airplane in preparation for the practical test
- 10 hours of solo flight training in a single-engine

Some of these dual hours can be combined but this is straight from [§61.109(a)](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-D/part-61/subpart-E/section-61.109)

Comment: Is 3 hours of cross-country night flight training by reference to instruments in a single engine airplane sufficient?

Comment: @Someone Yes, that should work. Realistically, once you get 3 hours of the required instrument time, you will have more than 3 hours of night and cross country time since taxi, takeoff, and landings are not instrument time so you will end up with about 3.5 of those two if you did 3 hours exact of instrument under those conditions.